# How to update header in Joomla component admin menu

Tags: joomla, components

I'm now developing a component for Joomla 1.5. I want to update the header part in the component menu for specfic actions like New/Edit/Add/Save, etc. How can I do that?

I'm attaching screenshots to make things more clear.

Component header part I want to change/update
[image: Component header part I want to change/update]

This is exactly the updating I meant
[image: This is exactly the updating I meant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the view.html.php under the specific component .

Then make a function and call it : initTitle()

```
public function initTitle() {
    JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('NEW_TITLE'), 'new');
}
```

if you want to add new buttons :

```
public function initToolBar($add=true) {
    JToolBarHelper::custom('save', 'saving', 'saving', JText::_('SAVE'), false);
    JToolBarHelper::spacer();
    JToolBarHelper::divider();
    JToolBarHelper::spacer();
    JToolBarHelper::custom('back', 'block', 'block', JText::_('CANCEL'), false);
}
```